# What makes a program require elevated privileges?

Tags: c#

What makes a program require elevated privileges?  Is there a way to find out?  I have a simple program that all it does is catch user session changes (lock, unlock, remote login, etc) and writes them to a remote sql database on the same network.  If it isn't run under a user account that is an admin, it crashes.

I know I can add a manifest file to make the program run in admin mode but I don't want uac invoked everytime a user logs in.

Is there another way?

Windows pops up a message saying SystemTrayApp has stopped working.  The Problem details are as follows:

Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:    CLR20r3

Problem Signature 01: systemtrayapp.exe

Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0

Problem Signature 03: 5579eff9

Problem Signature 04: System.Data

Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.17929

Problem Signature 06: 4ffa5c76

Problem Signature 07: 1ec1

Problem Signature 08: 10b

Problem Signature 09: System.Data.SqlClient.Sql

OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48

Locale ID:    1033

Additional Information 1: 0a9e

Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Additional Information 3: 0a9e

Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Write a Windows Service?

Comment: Catch the exception, inspect the message. Or since it already crashed, check the event log for the stack trace.

Comment: @xanatos no, you don't want a Windows Service with administrative privileges unless for very specific reasons. _"Because otherwise my program would crash on an exception"_ is not such a reason.

Comment: What is the crash message?  That will reveal what API it's crashing on.

Comment: @CodeCaster On my PC I have a `BingDesktopUpdater` running as SYSTEM! The threshold is quite low. If he needs some priviledged API, running as a service is an option. Clearly if the problem is buggy code, then solving the bugs is better.

Comment: I've added the crash details that windows kicks back.

Comment: @FLAdmin You should really add some logging... still `System.Data.SqlClient.Sql` is quite clear :-)

Comment: @xanatos "because someone else does it" also isn't a good reason. The Bing Desktop Updater service needs to write in C:\Program Files to update Bing Desktop.

Comment: It looks like your user isn't allowed to write to that database. You need the stack trace and the exception message.

Comment: .  If I add a user to the local admins group the program runs fine.  So I don't immediately see how it's because the user can't write to the db.  I'll set the creditinals explicitly though instead of integrated just to see.

Comment: @FLAdmin If you use integrated authentication, and the SQL db is local, all the users of the admin group are automathically granted full access to the SQL db

Comment: The db is on a remote server.

Comment: You should use a windows service with a service account that has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: I've thought about that but the program would not work correctly on a Terminal Server.